# How to implement SSO in Java with SAML?

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, cuba-platform

My application uses cuba.platform as framework and I want to implement a LoginProvider. Here is some documentation about this:

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.8/web_login.html?_ga=2.22865267.938183531.1520173474-888291717.1510758296

Is there a simple way to implement this "LoginProvider" of the documentation above to support SAML?

I tried to find some open source frameworks, but it was hard to find good tutorials or good documentation about this topic.

So, how is I can implement this LoginProvider?

Comment: The common way for Java / SAML is Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

SAML2 is a fairly simple flow and LoginProvider would have to handle it looking at the diagram. From the page:

> login() - authenticates a user, starts a session and changes the state
>   of the connection

so by the time `login()` is invoked you should be in possession of the SAML attributes for the user. Instead of the standard username/password flow for LoginProvider (by what that page says), you would need to do:

- find out which IdP the user is associated with, i.e. get the entityID of the IdP
- load the SSO endpoint for the entityID from its SAML metadata
- redirect the browser to the SSO endpoint with a SAMLRequest
- receive the redirected browser at your LoginProvider to get the SAMLResponse
- parse the SAML attributes from the SAMLResponse
- `login()`